# Can't understand why I'm getting segmentation fault due to strncpy

Tags: c, malloc

I am getting a segmentation fault when I use `strncpy` and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Here is my `rectangle.h` file. This is just a header file.

```
#define NAMESIZE 20

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct rectangle {
    struct point upperleft;
    struct point lowerright;
    //char label[NAMESIZE + 1];
    char *label;
};

struct point *create_point(int x, int y);

struct rectangle *create_rectangle(struct point ul, struct point lr, 
                                   char *label);

int area1(struct rectangle r);
int area2(struct rectangle *r);
void change_label(struct rectangle *r, char *newlabel);
void broken_change_label(struct rectangle r, char * newlabel);
void print_rectangle(struct rectangle *r);
```

This is my `rectangle.c` file. I am just going to show one function from it:

/* create_rectangle dynamically allocates memory to store a rectangle, gives it
 * initial values, and returns a pointer to the newly created rectangle.
 */

```
struct rectangle *create_rectangle(struct point ul, struct point lr, 
                                   char *label) {

    struct rectangle *r = malloc(sizeof(struct rectangle));
    /* TASK 1: fill in the rest of this function */
    r->upperleft = ul;
    r->lowerright = lr;
    r->label = malloc(strlen(label) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(r->label, label, strlen(label) + 1);

    return r;
}
```

In the above code, I use `malloc` to allocate enough space for the label pointer.

When I run the `tester.c` program below, I get a segmentation fault error (due to the `strncpy`).

```
int main(void) {    

    char *str1 = "Big rectangle";
    char *str2 = "Square";

    struct point *p1 = create_point(10, 10);
    struct point *p2 = create_point(100, 100);

    struct rectangle *r1 = create_rectangle(*p1, *p2, str1);
    print_rectangle(r1);
    printf("    expecting: (10, 10) (100, 100) Big rectangle\n");

    free(p2);
    p2 = create_point(20, 20);

    struct rectangle r2;

    strncpy(r2.label, str2, NAMESIZE); //GETTING SEGMENTATION FAULT DUE TO THIS LINE
}
```

I suspect that I am getting a segmentation fault error because I am doing `strncpy` directly on `r2.label`.  I suspect that because I am not allocating any space to `char *label` in the rectangle struct is why I am getting a segmentation fault error. But when I write

```
char *label = malloc(sizeof(NAMESIZE) * sizeof(char));
```

I get an error:

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration list` error.
```

Comment: Consider carefully whether `strncpy` is really the right tool for the job. It's *not* just a "safer" `strcpy`. See [my rant on the topic](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html), as well as question 13.2 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). (I'm not suggesting that this is the cause of the problem you're seeing.)

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(NAMESIZE) * sizeof(char))` - what? `NAMESIZE` is an int so this probably allocates 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like, as you said, you aren't allocating any memory for your `char* label`.

Do:

```
r2.label = malloc(sizeof(NAMESIZE) * sizeof(char));`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
strncpy(r2.label, str2, NAMESIZE);
```

You are trying to write to `r2.label`, which is a pointer that hasn't been allocated any space.

And be careful with the code that you did allocate space:

```
r->label = malloc(strlen(label) * sizeof(char));
```

`strlen(label)` is not enough, a string needs to be null-terminated.

Comment: What happens if a string is not null terminated?

Comment: Then it isn't a string. The meaning of *string* is: series of characters followed by a null-terminator.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
r->label = malloc(strlen(label) * sizeof(char));
strncpy(r->label, label, strlen(label) + 1);
```

should be:

```
r->label = malloc( strlen(label) + 1 );
strcpy( r->label, label );
```

- You  need to allocate space for the null terminator.
- `sizeof(char)` is always `1`
- The `strcpy` function finishes after writing `strlen(label)+1` bytes, so it is redundant to try and use `strncpy`.

`strncpy` is fairly dangerous in general because sometimes it does not output a string; my advice would be to never use it.

Further down,

```
strncpy(r2.label, str2, NAMESIZE);
```

is wrong because `r2.label` is currently a wild pointer. You also need to allocate memory in the same way:

```
r2.label = malloc( strlen(str2) + 1 );
strcpy( r2.label, str2 );
```

Comment: Is there any way to reserve space for the label string literal in the structure itself?

Something like: char *label = malloc(sizeof(NAMESIZE) + 1);

Comment: Yes, change to `char label[NAMESIZE + 1];`

Comment: Stop writing `sizeof(NAMESIZE)`.  `NAMESIZE` is `20`. `sizeof(NAMESIZE)` means `sizeof(20)`, i.e. the number of bytes required to store the int `20`. Which is `sizeof(int)`, which is 4 or 8 on common systems.

Answer (score 0):

You `malloc` `strlen(label)` bytes for the label in `create_rectangle`, then copy in `strlen(label)+1` bytes.  Note that, if the new label you are copying in is longer, you'll overflow that allocation.  But as @YuHao points out, it doesn't matter, because you never initialized any of the fields of `r2` (in particular, `label`).

Answer (score 0):

```
r->label = malloc(strlen(label) * sizeof(char));
```

You are mising allocation for terminating character, it should be

```
r->label = malloc((strlen(label)+1) * sizeof(char));
```